# Degree of $K(s)/K(s^n)$ and linear independence of powers of $s$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I am stuck on the following exercise:

> Let $K$ be any field and $s$ an indeterminate. Then $K(s)$ is a field extension of $K(s^n)$. Prove that $[K(s):K(s^n)]=n$. Hence show that the minimum polynomial of $s$ over $K(s^n)$ is $t^n-s^n$.
>
> *[Hint: first show that $s$ satisfies a polynomial of degree $n$ over $K(s^n)$; this gives $\leq$. Then show that $\{1,s,\ldots,s^{n-1}\}$ is linearly independent over $K(s^n)$; this gives you $\geq$.]*

I am trying to use the hint:

I let $f(t) = t^n-s^n$ hence $f(s) = 0$ which means that $[K(s):K(s^n)] \leq n$

Now I try to prove the linear independence:

Suppose $1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \alpha_{i} s^i = 0$ I am trying to show all $\alpha_i = 0$. My plan was to somehow apply $f$ to that but I am having no luck.

Comment: Where do your $\alpha_i$ live?

Comment: @Servaes in $K$

Comment: The hint tells you to show that $\{1,s,\ldots,s^{n-1}\}$ are linearly independent over $K(s^n)$, so your $\alpha_i$ should be in $K(s^n)$.

Comment: @Servaes I see. I can use this to get a contradiction as then $\sum_i \alpha_i s^i$ is of degree $> n$ if I knew the minimum polynomial however I have not yet proved the minimum polynomial is of degree $n$ - I am supposed to conclude it after this (not sure how).

Comment: No. Use the fact that $s$ is an indeterminate; it is not the root of any polynomial over $K$.

Comment: What was the "no" towards to? I thought an indeterminate meant that $s$ was simply unknown.

Comment: The "No" was towards your entire previous comment. The entire statement of the exercise is false if $s$ is algebraic over $K$.

Comment: @Servaes alright, so if $\alpha _i \in K(s^2)$ then assuming $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha_i s^i = 0$ would this not give a polynomial $g$ of degree $>n$ which satisfies $g(s) = 0$ which contradicts the first statement I proved (the one with $f$) hence only possible if all $a_i = 0$?

Comment: Almost. Why $\deg g>n$? Note that $K\subset K(s^n)$, so $g$ can have any degree.

Comment: @Servaes I figured that if $\alpha_i \in K(s^2)$ then each $\alpha_i$ is of the form say $1 + s^2$ or $s^2$ or $1 + s^4 + s^6$ for example, so the $s^{n-1}a_{i}$ term would have degree $n-1 + 2 = n+1$. But I am not sure what you mean by $g$ can have any degree?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose toward a contradiction that $\{1,s,\ldots,s^{n-1}\}$ is linearly dependent over $K(s^n)$. Then there exist $\alpha_0(s^n),\ldots,\alpha_{n-1}(s^n)\in K(s^n)$, not all zero, such that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\alpha_i(s^n)\cdot s^i=0$. We may write $\alpha_i(s^n)=\frac{p_i(s^n)}{q_i(s^n)}$ with $p_i(s^n),q_i(s^n)\in K[s^n]$, so that clearing out denominators in the expression 
$$0=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\alpha_i(s^n)\cdot s^i=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{p_i(s^n)}{q_i(s^n)}\cdot s^i,$$ 
yields an expression $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}r_i(s^n)\cdot s^i=0$ with $r_i(s^n)\in K[s^n]$ given by
$$r_i(s^n):=p_i(s^n)\cdot\prod_{\substack{j=0\\j\neq i}}^{n-1}q_j(s^n).$$
Now consider the polynomial $f(X)\in K[X]$ given by
$$f(X):=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}r_i(X^n)\cdot X^i.$$
It is a polynomial over $K$ which has $s$ as a root, contradicting the fact that $s$ is an indeterminate. Hence $\{1,s,\ldots,s^{n-1}\}$ is linearly independent.

---

**Exercise:** Why doesn't this argument work for $\{1,s,\ldots,s^n\}$?

Comment: Sorry but how does that contradict that $s$ is a indeterminant. Is that not just something that is unknown?

Comment: I am using this one: The term "indeterminate" is sometimes used as a synonym for unknown or variable (Becker and Weispfenning 1993, p. 188).
from wolframalpha

Comment: Look up the definition used in the document in which you found the exercise.

Comment: It's not defined, that's why I had to google it. Thank you for your solution however I'll look through it now

Comment: Otherwise, show that the statement is false when $s$ is algebraic over $K$. For example, what happens when $s\in K$?

Comment: so I am guessing indeterminate means a unknown variable K(s^n) only?

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand that contradiction of the $s$ being an indeterminate part - could you elaborate on how this is a ocntradiction.

Comment: Nevermind! I understand now. Thanks for your help - for the proving $f$ as my original post is the minimal polynomial, is there any way ot do it without using eisensteins?

Comment: Would anyone care to motivate the sudden downvote?